# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'question_response'

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-3.7

I am trying to plot a bar chart for the followig data set

```
                                                                                          qr_count
question_title                                                    question_response
The course recommended books etc. are relevant and appropriate:          agree               116
The course workload is manageable:                                       agree               112
I think I have made progress in the course:                              agree               111
The Course is well organized / updated :                                 agree               103
The course contents increased my knowledge of the subject:               agree               103
```

I have extracted this dataframe from another dataframe using this approach

```
 each_qt_count = new_merge_data[['question_title', 'question_response']].value_counts()
each_qt_count = pd.DataFrame(each_qt_count)
each_qt_count.rename(columns={0:'qr_count'}, inplace=True)
each_qt_count.head()
```

new_merge_data has following rows

```
Index(['question_id', 'question_title', 'course_title', 'course_code',
   'course_assign_id', 'id', 'question_response', 'student_id',
   'date_created'],
  dtype='object')
```

now I am trying to plot each_qt_count using this approach

```
plt.bar(each_qt_count.question_response, each_qt_count.qr_count)
```

it is giving me this error

**AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'question_response'**

please help me how can I plot bar chart for this dataframe?

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: how did you generate `each_qt_count` can you provide the code? also paste the output of `print(each_qt_count.columns)`

Comment: i have edited my post now please check and its the output of 'print(each_qt_count.columns)' is Index(['question_response_count'], dtype='object')

Comment: your code leads me beileve that question_title & question_response are not the index of the dataframe (which is what your sample looks like) can you `print(new_merge_data.columns)` and `print(new_merge_data.index)` post it in your question, for one `value_counts()` is used on a series and _not_ a dataframe which is what you are doing. I don't think your code gets passed the first line

Comment: thanks for the edits, I think you can use `new_merge_data.groupby('question_title')['question_response'].size().plot(kind='bar')` side note you may want to categorize your questions for display purposes.